# Importing data from excel into R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I imported some data from a csv file.

There are 13 columns each column is a year.

The first column is a list of the months.

The first column is showing up as a data set as you can see in the plot picture.

Should I just delete this column? Or is there a way to let R know to remove this?

Also

Why is there an X in front of the years?

And why is there an extra data set X?

```
Arrivals <-read.csv("Arrivals.csv")
library(fpp2)
library(forecast)
Adata <- ts(Arrivals, frequency=12, start=c(2001,1))
autoplot(Adata)
```

[image: autoplot function]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: please include the data with using `dput(Arrivals)` or `dput(head(Arrivals))` if it's big, we don't know your data

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to NULL

```
Arrivals$X <- NULL
```

If X is the name of the column of the months